# What would be the correct way to trace a robot image using arrays?

Tags: arrays, image-processing, graphics, clion

The issue I am dealing with is figuring out setting up to trace the image of this "robot" with arrays and with the set graphics. How would I go tracing it to not be exact, but to where it could resemble the image?

UPDATE: So I tried putting in the code below, and now it won't run due to this issue.

"C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\demo.dir\build.make:102: demo.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]:**  [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:72: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62SmS.png):  **[CMakeFiles\Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/demo.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: demo] Error 2"

[image]

```
int data[12] = {
    0, 50, 50, 25,
    1, 200, 125, 100, 275, 200, 375,
    9
};
```

#### Attempt

```
void drawScene(void) {

    int index = 0;
    int shape_type;
    int done = 0;

    clearWindow();
    setColor(YELLOW);
    index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<2;i++) {
        shape_type = data[index];     // this should be the shape code
        index = index + 1;      // now index point to the first parameter
        switch(shape_type) {
            case 0: // circle
                drawFilledCircle(
                   data[index], data[index+1], data[index+2]);
                index = index + 3;
                break;
            case 1: // triangle
                drawFilledTriangle(
                    data[index], data[index+1], 
                    data[index+2], data[index+3], 
                    data[index+4], data[index+5]);
                index = index + 6;
                break;
            default: // done with shape loop
                done = 1;
        }
        if (done == 1) break;
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"trace"*? What will the output look like?

Comment: Trace as in drawing the figure, and the output, using graphics.h and graphics cpp, making a drawn image; not exact as in the image, but to where it resembles a "robot" using data,(circles, triangles, squares, etc.)